# Background image not saving in WordPress Customizer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to set a background image in the WordPress Customizer. I can upload the image and see it preview in Customizer but after I save it, its not appearing on the live site.

I have the following code in my customizer.php file:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'section_1_background_image', array(
    'default'           => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default.jpg',
       'transport'      => 'postMessage',
) );    
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'section_1_background_image_control', array(
    'label'             => __('Background Image','minisite'),
    'settings'          => 'section_1_background_image',
    'section'           => 'section_1',
    'priority' => 10,
) ) );
```

and the corresponding code in my customizer.js file

```
wp.customize( 'section_1_background_image', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $('#wrapper-1').css('background-image', newval );
    } );
} );
```

This same setup works fine for background colors but I believe it has to do with "url" needing to be output in the css in front of the background-image filename, which it isn't doing.

I also tried the following with no success:

```
wp.customize( 'section_1_background_image', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $('#wrapper-1').css('background-image', 'url("' + newval + '")' );
    } );
} );
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the correct code for displaying it in the Customizer was:

```
wp.customize( 'section_1_background_image', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $('#wrapper-1').css('background-image', 'url("' + newval + '")' );
    } );
} );
```

However, this wasn't the problem for saving it properly on the front end. That was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773977/wordpress-customizer-css-for-background-image/40774196?noredirect=1#comment68774211_40774196).

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the option to add background images when you navigate to `Appearance -> Customize` in WordPress' admin I typically provide the option to customize the background through [`custom-background`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds) in my functions.php:

```
$custom_background = array(
    'default-color'             => '00ff00',
    'default-image'             => get_template_directory() . '/img/default_background.png',
    'background-repeat'         => 'tile',
    'default-position-x'        => 'center',
    'background-attachment'     => 'fixed',
    'wp-head-callback'          => '_custom_background_cb'
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $custom_background );
```

Comment: I think this is intended more for a custom page background image but I'm using mine several times throughout the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the control wrong.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'section_1_background_image', array(
    'default'        => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default.jpg',
    'transport'      => 'postMessage',
) );    
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'section_1_background_image', array(
    'label'             => __('Background Image','minisite'),
    'settings'          => 'section_1_background_image',
    'section'           => 'section_1',
    'priority' => 10,
) ) );
```

The name in the `WP_Customize_Image_Control` should be same as the setting name.

You're referencing the `section_1_background_image_control`, and the setting name is `section_1_background_image`.

**EDIT**

To make your image appear, you need to add in your javascript (I'm following the twenty fifteen theme here)

```
( function( $ ) {
    var style = $( '#twentysixteen-color-scheme-css' ),
        api = wp.customize;

    if ( ! style.length ) {
        style = $( 'head' ).append( '<style type="text/css" id="twentysixteen-color-scheme-css" />' )
                            .find( '#twentysixteen-color-scheme-css' );
    }

    api( 'section_1_background_image', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
            var background_image = 'body{ background-image: url( ' + newval + '); }'
            style.text( background_image );
        } );
    } );


} )( jQuery );
```

Where you toggle all your live changes. I added the image to the `body`, but you can change that to `#wrapper-1`

```
var background_image = '#wrapper-1{ background-image: url( ' + newval + '); }'
```

**EDIT 2**

This also works for me:

```
wp.customize( 'section_1_background_image', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("' + newval + '")' );
    } );
} );
```

Just replace `body` with `#wrapper-1`.

Just realized, you've said that when you save the image, the wrapper doesn't have saved the image. Did you create a `dynamic-css.php` where you'll place all the custom css?

Usually I create a `dynamic-css.php` where I place `$custom_css` variable and place the results of the customizer in.

```
$section_1_background_image= get_theme_mod( 'section_1_background_image', '' );
if ( '' !== $section_1_background_image) {
    $custom_css .= '#wrapper-1{background-image: url("' . esc_attr( $body_background ) . '");}';
}
```

Then I define the same variable in my `functions.php` and add it as an inline style:

```
$custom_css = '';
wp_add_inline_style( 'main_css', $custom_css );
```

Where `main_css` is the hook name where you call the `get_stylesheet_uri()`. This code must go after the main stylesheet enqueue.

Comment: Oh, I always thought those names were supposed to be different. It actually works fine for a background color but even when I change the settings to match, it still doesn't work for the background image.

Comment: @TroyTempleman I've updated the code. Tested it on twenty fifeteen theme, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks @dingo_d, that looks like a good solution but not really a fix to my existing code, which I prefer to keep the same. I have a lot of other background images setup the same way :) I think it's simply a formatting issue with the newval.