# WordPress customizer image output in front end, not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I saw "[Background image not saving in WordPress Customizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769165/background-image-not-saving-in-wordpress-customizer)"
But didn't get any help.

My code is

```
function sorcey_customize_register($wp_customize){

    $wp_customize->add_section('sorcey_footer', array(
      'title'    => __('Footer', 'sorcey'),
      'description' => '',
      'priority' => 120,
));

/*  =============================
  Footer logo
===============================*/
$wp_customize->add_setting('sorcey_footer_logo', array(
  'default'        => '',
  'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
  'type'           => 'text',
));
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( 
$wp_customize, 'sorcey_footer_logo_ctrl', array(
    'label'         => __( 'Footer Logo', 'sorcey' ),
    'section'       => 'sorcey_footer',
    'settings' => 'sorcey_footer_logo',
    'height'        => '40px',
    'width'         => '160px',
    'button_labels' => array(
        'select'       => __( 'Select logo' ),
        'change'       => __( 'Change logo' ),
        'remove'       => __( 'Remove' ),
        'default'      => __( 'Default' ),
        'placeholder'  => __( 'No logo selected' ),
        'frame_title'  => __( 'Select logo' ),
        'frame_button' => __( 'Choose logo' ),
    ),
    )
));
}
```

I Tryed for output by

```
echo get_theme_mod( 'sorcey_footer_logo' );
```

And

```
echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_theme_mod( 'sorcey_footer_logo' ) );
```

And

```
var_dump(get_theme_mod( 'sorcey_footer_logo' ));
```

But showing 'boolean false'

Comment: Anyone have any idea?